# PDE list of equations, derivative for boundarry condition evaluates to true

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to do a basic 2D wave equation PDE in mathematica (version 11). I have a set of equations

Edit: I have infact made sure I cleared u

```
Clear[u]

wave2deqs = {
D[u[t, x, y], t, t] - Laplacian[u[t, x, y] , {x, y}] == 0, 
u[0, x, y] == Exp[-((x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2)],
D[u[0, x, y], t] == 0}
```

This works fine except for

```
D[u[0, x, y], t] == 0
```

evaluates to 'True', and then when I put this into

```
wave2d = NDSolveValue[wave2deqs, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1} ]
```

I naturally get an error that eqlist is not a list of equations.

So my question is, why would

```
D[u[0, x, y], t] == 0
```

even evaluate to a boolean rather than being another equation?

I followed this examples for reference:
https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/solve-a-wave-equation-in-2d.html which is in mathematica 10, but seems ridiculous that this wouldn't work.

Comment: You probably have lingering definitions. Try `Clear[u]` followed by `NDSolveValue` again.

Comment: I definitely do this, I just didn't include it here. Sorry, I'll add it above. Thanks. Edit: That wasn't the issue btw.

Comment: You're right. The problem is `u[0,x,y]` doesn't have `t`, so the derivative is 0. Perhaps `Derivative[1,0,0][u][0,x,y] == 0` would work better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way that `D[u[0,x,y],t]==0` is **not** true. You are asking Mathematica to calculate the derivative of an expression  of a parameter that the expression does not contain. `u[0,x,y]` is such an expression - no `t` involved. So the derivative is quite naturally and correctly equal to zero.

What you need to do is to tell Mathematica that you like to calculate the (first) derivative of `u` of its first parameter and that that derivative shall be zero.

```
Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0
```

This is, by the way, the method used on the website you refer to.

Comment: I figured something like this would probably be the problem. I have seldom seen this notation for a derivative though. Thanks, I'll have to read up on the difference between D[...] and Derivative[].

Answer (score 3):

Another way is, first take derivative w.r.t `t` using `D[u[t, x, y], t]`  then replace the variable `t` by a specific value using `/.value`.

Thus the derivative condition can be describe alternatively like this,

```
(D[u[t, x, y], t] /. t -> 0) == 0
```